# How to get the sum of items in selected index in PyQt5 QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I would like to get the sum of selected items in the currentRow and show it on the same row of obviously a different column when the enter key is pressed

[image]

this is the code which get data from database

```
def pay1(self):
    con = mdb.connect(host='', user='',password='')
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("USE table_1")
    x = "SELECT player_name,total,time FROM paid"
    cur.execute(x)
    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
    self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(0, 100)
    self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(1, 130)
    self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(2, 130)
    self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(3, 130)
    self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, 
    QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem('Player Name'))
    self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, 
    QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem('Total Amount'))
    self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, 
    QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem('Time and Date'))

    for row_number, row_data in enumerate(cur):
        self.tableWidget.insertRow(row_number)
        for column_number, data in enumerate(row_data):
            self.tableWidget.setItem(row_number, column_number, 
            QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))
    con.commit()
```

Comment: Could you explain me better, according to the image you want to add "560", "560", "786" and "560" But in what item (row and column) do you want to show it?

Comment: i want to show it on any empty row @eyllanesc

Comment: As I understand you, it is enough to print the sum in the console, am I correct?

Comment: i want to print it on row 1 column 4 @eyllanesc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To capture the event of the pressed enter key you must use `QShortCut`, to obtain the selected items you must use the `selectedIndexes()` method of the `QTableWidget` as shown below:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import random

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Print me")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(button)
        lay.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        self.fill_table()

        QtWidgets.QShortcut(
            self.tableWidget,
            key=QtGui.QKeySequence(QtCore.Qt.Key_Return),
            context=QtCore.Qt.WidgetShortcut,
            activated=self.sum_selected
        )

    def fill_table(self):
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(4)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        for i, width in enumerate((100, 130, 130, 130)):
            self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(i, width)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Player Name', 'Total Amount', 'Time and Date'])

        for i in range(40):
            self.tableWidget.insertRow(self.tableWidget.rowCount())
            it = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(random.randint(100, 150)))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(i, 1, it)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def sum_selected(self):
        result = sum([float(ix.data()) for ix in self.tableWidget.selectedIndexes() if ix.column() == 1])
        r, c = 0, 3
        it = self.tableWidget.item(r, c)
        if it is None:
            it = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(result))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(r, c, it)
        else:
            it.setText(str(result))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: i want to ask you that how can i disable qtablewidget items. if i click on ''hamza'' it turn blue means it is checked how can i avoid it @eyllanesc

Comment: @user8055917 What do you mean by "hamza"?

Comment: you can see ''hamza'' in image @eyllanesc